# register Single File Components globally

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm going straight to the point here, I'm creating a registration form using VUEJS. However, when I try to register the component globally it gives me error.
 Please bear with me I'm still new to vuejs.

when I check the console it gives me this error:

> n is not a function

Thanks in advance for the help.

here's my code:

**index.php file**

```
<section id="app" class="homepage">
   <div class="content">
    <?php
        $this->load->view($content);
    ?>
   </div>
</section>

<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/js/vue.min.js" ></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/js/vue-resource.min.js" ></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/js/app.js" ></script>
```

**app.js file**

```
Vue.component("tour-form", './components/tourForm.vue');

const app =  new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data(){
        return{
        }
    }
});
```

**tour_form.php file**

```
<tour-form></tour-form>
```

Comment: Is `tour_form.php` being loaded by `$this->load->view($content)`?

Comment: @skribe yes sir you are correct.

Answer (score 3):

`Vue.component()` takes the component options ( an object `{}` ) as its 2nd argument

But you are passing the path of the vue component as a string.

Since you are using `.vue` files you mivht be using `vue-loader` to parse these files.

`vue-loader`  transforms the component into a plain javascript module.

So import the component and pass it as the second argument

```
import TourForm from './components/tourForm.vue'

Vue.component("tour-form", TourForm);

const app =  new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data(){
        return{
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The normal way to do register a component globaly is like `Vue.component('tour-form', require('./components/tourForm.vue'))`

Comment: @skribe you can use `require` also

Comment: I was just suggesting doing it all in one line, not that yours was wrong. :)

Comment: hello guys, I've tried doing the import also... but still it gives me error.. is it because I am just using a CDN?

Comment: @SamTengWong are you using vue-loader to compile .vue files

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Hi, All I know is I'm not using webpack... this is not a standalone vuejs... I'm just using a CDN vuejs to work with..